# Regex to match four repeated letters in a string using a Java pattern

Tags: java, regex, character

I want to match something like aaaa, aaaad, adjjjjk. Something like ([a-z])\1+ was used to match the repeated characters, but I am not able to figure this out for four letters.

Comment: Hey guys cool answers but i have one concern
"ffffffff".matches("([a-z])\\1{3,}") = true
"fffffasdf".matches("([a-z])\\1{3,}") = false
"asdffffffasdf".matches("([a-z])\\1{3,}") = false

what can i do for the bottom two?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not knowing about the finite repetition syntax, your own problem solving skill should lead you to this:

```
([a-z])\1\1\1
```

Obviously it's not pretty, but:

- It works
- It exercises your own problem solving skill
- It may lead you to deeper understanding of concepts

  - In this case, knowing the desugared form of the finite repetition syntax

---

> I have a concern:
>
> - `"ffffffff".matches("([a-z])\\1{3,}") = true`
> - `"fffffasdf".matches("([a-z])\\1{3,}") = false`
> - `"asdffffffasdf".matches("([a-z])\\1{3,}") = false`
>
> What can I do for the bottom two?

The problem is that in Java, `matches` need to match the whole string; it is as if the pattern is surrounded by `^` and `$`.

Unfortunately there is no `String.containsPattern(String regex)`, but you can always use this trick of surrounding the pattern with `.*`:

```
"asdfffffffffasf".matches(".*([a-z])\\1{3,}.*") // true!
//                         ^^              ^^
```

Comment: If you are trying to match a string where the string you look for is just before an end of line character, the pattern above won't match. (I learnt that the hard way!). You could do: '"asdfffffffffasf".matches(".*([a-z])\\1{3,}(?s).*")' where '(?s)' triggers the matching for end of line chars.

Comment: it is best to find character repeating.

Comment: I have been looking for this since last 2 hours. Thank you very much

Answer (score 25):

You want to match a single character and then that character repeated three more times:

```
([a-z])\1{3}
```

Note: In Java you need to escape the backslashes inside your regular expressions.

---

**Update**: The reason why it isn't doing what you want is because you are using the method [`matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) which requires that the string exactly matches the regular expression, not just that it contains the regular expression. To check for containment you should instead use the [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class. Here is some example code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z])\\1{3}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("asdffffffasdf");
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
true
```

Answer (score 6):

You can put `{n}` after something to match it `n` times, so:

```
([a-z])\1{3}
```

Answer (score 3):

General regex pattern for predefinite repetition is `{4}`.

Thus here ([a-z])\1{3} should match your 4 chars.