# What is a regular expression to find if string contains only repeating characters?

Tags: java, regex, string

I've already gone through:
[Regex to match four repeated letters in a string using a Java pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622776/regex-to-match-4-repeated-letters-in-string-using-java-pattern)
and
[Regular expression to match any character being repeated more than 10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660694/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-being-repeated-more-than-10-times)

But they aren't useful in my case. They are fine if I just want to check if a string is containing repeated characters (like 1111, abccccd, 12aaaa3b, etc.). What I want is to check if string is comprising entirely of repeated characters only i.e. aabb111, 1111222, 11222aaa, etc.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Do the repeated characters have to be adjacent?

Comment: you mean to say that every character should be repeated right.. ?

Comment: Yeah.. the string should only contain repeated characters. So strings like 111222az shouldn't return true when compared with the regex pattern

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `((.)\2+)+` as pattern:

```
String pattern = "((.)\\2+)+";
System.out.println("a".matches(pattern));        // false
System.out.println("1aaa".matches(pattern));     // false
System.out.println("aa".matches(pattern));       // true
System.out.println("aabb111".matches(pattern));  // true
System.out.println("1111222".matches(pattern));  // true
System.out.println("11222aaa".matches(pattern)); // true
System.out.println("etc.".matches(pattern));     // false
```

About the pattern:

- `(...)`: capture matched part as group. (starting from 1)

  ```
  ((.)\2+)+
  ^^ 
  |+----- group 2
  +----- group 1
  ```
- `(.)`: match any character (except newline) and capture it as group **2** (because it come after enclosing parenthesis).
- `\2`: backreference to the matched group. If `(.)` matched a character `x`, `\2` matches another `x` (not any character, but only `x`).
- `PATTERN+`: matches one or more matches of PATTERN.
- `(.)\2+`: match repeating characters greedy.

Comment: Good stuff +1, but might be an idea to explain; you're using a back inserter.

Comment: Does this really match `aaa`? As in, why not `(.)(\1)*`?

Comment: @EmilLundberg, It will return true for `1`. Also it will return false for `aaa111`.

Comment: The pattern would perhaps have been more obvious with a non-capturing outer group.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Yes it would. But I wished to make a shorter one.

Comment: @falsetru: Looks great.. gotta try it out. Before that, a small query.. if i replace (.) with ([a-zA-Z0-9]), it will match only those characters right? OR is there another shorter way to denote characters in range [a-zA-Z0-9]?

Comment: @KiranParmar you can shorten `[0-9]` to `[\d]`, but beware that this doesn't work everywhere. For instance, in `grep` the corresponding "shortcut" is `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: @KiranParmar, You can use word character \w. But it also matches an underscore (_). See [Java Platform SE documentation - Summary of regular-expression constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: @falsetru: In that case,  ([a-zA-Z0-9]) works well for my requirements. Thanks for the answer :)
I wish I knew how to come up with such regular-expressions. I've tried understanding it multiple times, but I always get confused when the information becomes too much. Any helpful pointers for people like me ?

Comment: @KiranParmar, How about read the documentation I linked in previous comment?

Comment: @falsetru: Seen it a lot of times, but I forget it on account of lack of use & as I said, it get's confusing as I move down. Anyways, thanks once again.

Comment: @falsetru: Out of curiosity, I tried ([a-zA-Z0-9])\2+ assuming it will return true if string contains only a single character being repeated for 2 or more times, like aaaa. But it returns false!
So what exactly will this regex return true for?

Comment: @KiranParmar, As I said in the answer, capturing group number starts from `1`. So it should be `([a-zA-Z0-9])\1+`. BTW, did you escape the backslash(`\ `) in the string literal?

Comment: @falsetru Yes I did. I thought number after \ meant that match that many characters. Just checked with the java doc & found that it means the group. Thanks for the help! :) By the way, how come you are always online when I ask something? :D

Comment: @KiranParmar, Hmm. Maybe my words is not clear in the answer.

Comment: @KiranParmar, Because your waking time overlaps with mine. And SO notify me when I get a mention. ;)