# Regex to determine if string is a single repeating character

Tags: java, regex, string, repeat

What is the regex pattern to determine if a string solely consists of a single repeating character?

e.g.

> "aaaaaaa"    = true 
>  "aaabbbb"    = false 
>  "$$$$$$$"    =
>   true

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302784/what-is-a-regular-expression-to-find-if-string-contains-only-repeating-character) question checks if a string only contains repeating characters (e.g. "aabb") however I need to determine if it is a **single** repeating character.

Comment: `^(.)\1+$` maybe? Depends on the language. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lS5aG7/1)

Comment: Oops Java, just added tag.

Comment: if someone wants opposite of this one, allow only if string doesn't contain same character start to end, this is the regex ^(?!(.)\1+$).* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610743/how-to-negate-any-regular-expression-in-java this link helped me to negate it

Comment: @PSatishPatro you could always just use the regix in the answer to this question with the java 'not' operator: !string.matches(^(.)\1{1,}$);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)

```
^(.)\1{1,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC3uO8/1)

Pattern Explanation:

```
^          the beginning of the string
(          group and capture to \1:
.          any character except \n
)          end of \1
\1{1,}     what was matched by capture \1 (at least 1 times)
$          the end of the string
```

---

Backreferences match the same text as previously matched by a capturing group. The backreference `\1` (backslash one) references the first capturing group. `\1` matches the exact same text that was matched by the first capturing group.

---

In Java you can try

```java
"aaaaaaaa".matches("(.)\\1+") // true
```

There is no need for `^` and `$` because `String.matches()` looks for whole string match.

Comment: I was needing to use the "Matches" operation and the java example above worked great.

Answer (score 10):

this really depends on your language but in general this would match a line with all the same character.

```
^(.)\1+$
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/lS5aG7/1)

- `^` assert position at start of a line
- 1st Capturing group `(.)`
- `\1+` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
  Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `$` assert position at end of a line