# Regex for a string made only of repeated chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a validation that determines if a string is only made of repeated chars.  So, for example it would catch "pp" but not "happy".

So far, I can check for the repeating char using this:

```
/(.)\1+/.test(value);
```

How can I change this regex to only catch "pp" and not catch "happy"? Would regex be the best way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29159039/5527985

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex is almost valid, you only have to add `^` and `$` respectively at the beginning and at the end, to ensure that the string doesn't contain any other characters:

```
/^(.)\1+$/.test(value);
```

See also a [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/xP3mM0/1).

Answer (score 1):

An inverse should also work.. ie, this regex should match a string which contain two non repeated characters or empty string. Negation `!` exists before the regex should do an inverse match.

```
> !/(.)(?!\1).|^$/.test('happy')
false
> !/(.)(?!\1).|^$/.test('')
false
> !/(.)(?!\1).|^$/.test('pp')
true
> !/(.)(?!\1).|^$/.test('ppo')
false
> !/(.)(?!\1).|^$/.test('ppppppppp')
true
>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xP3mM0/2)

Comment: You are essentially saying, return true if it not the case that there is some subsequent character different than the first one. In what ways is this better than a regexp which just says return true if all the subsequent characters are the same?