# Identifying records where string is made up of repeating characters

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am interested in identifying records where a string is made up of 1 repeating character such as
'AAA', 'ZZZZZ', 'EE'
But not
'A', 'HELLO', 'APPLE', 'AABB', 'MM ALBERT'

The following regex works when I test it `^(.)\1{1,}$`
https://regex101.com/r/dT6dK8/46
But it does not work when I am using it in Snowflake.
Any advice would be appreciated.

What I am testing in Snowflake

```
SELECT 'AA' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT TRUE'
       ,'AAA' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT TRUE'
       ,'A' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT FALSE'
       ,'AAAAA' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT TRUE'
       ,'BBBB' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT TRUE'
       ,'AABB' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT FALSE'
       ,'HELLO' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT FALSE'       
       ,'AAAAA' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT TRUE'
       ,'BB BB' regexp '^(.)\1{1,}$' -- AS 'EXPECT FALSE'
;
```

**References**
[Regex to determine if string is a single repeating character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158996/regex-to-determine-if-string-is-a-single-repeating-character)

Comment: Does `'^(.)\\1+$'` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using regexp:

```
SELECT col, REPLACE(col, LEFT(col,1), '') = '' AND LENGTH(col) > 1
FROM (SELECT 'AA' AS col UNION ALL SELECT 'HELLO') t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=940fb7257faeeecfe7eed68bda7cc9e7)**

If replacement by using first character with empty string returns empty string it means that all were the same.

Comment: Thats clever solution. If the string is made up of all the same characters then replacing the first char with all '' would make it an empty string.
However that does not solve the case to allow for Single Char Strings. where 'A' is a valid entry

Comment: This doesn’t work for a string made of a single character. You might need to add a condition on the length of the string.

Comment: `IF(LEN(col) = 1, col, REPLACE(col, LEFT(col,1), ''))` would fix 1-letter issue.

Comment: Thanks for nitpicking and both ideas :)

Comment: By adding an AND statement with it easily solves the Single Character problem.
I appreciate the help.
I am still curious though, why it doesn't work for Snowflake but in the regex tester